# printing similar words from a string-c

Tags: c, string

i'm new in c programming and i need some help with this function because i cant figure it out,
i need to make a function that receives a string and prints out the similar words (the order of the letters ,the amount of the letters and if the letters are capital or small doesn't matter) for example:
if received "Nanny have you any cheap peach?"
the output is:

> Nanny any
>
> cheap peach

i can't use pointers ,and cant use string.h library.
i tried and came up with this but i had no luck on figuring it out

```
void FindSimilarWords(char str2[]){
    int f,i,j,last,count=0,count1=0,k,letter,temp=0;
    char word1[wordsize],word2[wordsize];

    for (i = SIZE2 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (str2[i] != ' ' && str2[i] != '\0')
        {
            last = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i<= last; i++)
    {
        k = 0;
        j = i;
        do {
            word1[k] = str2[j];
            k++;
            j++;
        } while (str2[j] != ' '&&str2[j] != '\0');

        word1[k] = '\0';
        for (letter =last; letter >= j-1; letter--)
        {
            temp = letter;
            while (temp != ' ')
            {
                count1++;
                temp--;
            }
            f = 0;
            for (k--; k >= 0; k--)
            {
                if (str2[j] == word1[k])
                {
                    count++;
                    word2[f] = str2[j];
                    f++;
                }
            }
            if (count == count1)
                printf("%s %s\n", word1, word2);
            else
                while (letter != ' ')
                    letter--;
        }
        while (str2[i] != ' ')
            i++;

    }
}
```

Comment: Very similar to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53683048/function-to-find-similar-words-string-c).

Comment: I might first start by breaking the individual words into tokens so that you have an array of `char` arrays with no spaces or punctuation (tokens).  Then I would go through each token and compare to each of the other tokens for whatever condition you require for similarity .  You will want to go through all **combinations** so you don't duplicate results.